# Navigating a Zipped Filesystem

Tags: archive

I have found that, with some file zippers like 7-Zip, it is possible to use files inside the created archives. For example, if I create a file `my-zip-file.7z`, containing folder `my-folder`, with files `this-file.docx` and `that-file.html` I can use 7zip to go into `my-zip-file.7z` and open the 2 files, and see or change the contents, even if the original `my-folder` is deleted! How is this possible?

Comment: If you look at the file path for whatever you're editing you'll see that the document is saved to a temporary folder. When you save (or possibly close) 7-Zip then updates the zip file with the saved content.

Comment: I figured it was something like that. Still useful, though. Could you make that an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the file path for whatever you're editing you'll see that the document is saved to a temporary folder. When you save (or possibly close) 7-Zip then updates the zip file with the saved content.