# Traverse Zipped Filesystem from Command Line

Tags: filesystems, compression, cross-platform, archive

Is there a way to traverse the files & folders inside an archive? For example, if I have a file `my-zip-file.zip`, could I do

```
ls -l my-zip-file.zip
```

or even

```
cd my-zip-file
```

I know there are the command `tar` and the command line version of `7-Zip`, but it seems like you can only do these things from outside the archive. Also, with `grep`, you can pretty much simulate the `ls` situation from this question, but much slower and, again, only from outside the archive.

With the GUI version of `7-Zip`, you can do pretty much all of this, just with a different shell, so I am looking for a command-line version. From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993955/navigating-a-zipped-filesystem) that I asked, it seems `7-Zip` does this by creating temporary folders to hold the represented files & folders, so this might be a bottleneck.

I would like this solution to be cross-platform, but I understand if that's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can effectively mount a zip file on the file system using [AVFS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/avf/).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. Is there any other page you could link to? That `sourceforge` page doesn't have much info.

Comment: `Sourceforge` says AVFS is for Solaris & Linux only. Is there anything else for Windows or OS X? Otherwise, since I have a Windows machine, does this work for `Git for Windows` or `Cygwin`?

Comment: I'm sure it wouldn't without modification.

Comment: OK, so is there anything else? My question asked for cross-platform if possible.

Comment: You still have not learned how to use google.  I had no idea, but a quick google search immediately turned up [this](http://mountziplibrary.codeplex.com/).  You will likely find such things on different platforms.  You will not find a single solution, since tying in to an operating system's file system will inherently be non-portable.

Comment: I meant is there anything else cross-platform you could put in your answer. What did you search for, though? I'm not seeing that site.

Comment: ["mount zip windows"](http://www.google.com/search?q=mount+zip+windows).  That google search also turns up a superuser answer with yet more solutions.

Comment: Oh, I never thought to use that term. I guess because I come from a Windows background and the mounting is abstracted more there.